# An immediate alternative to a trigonometry problem (high school)

Tags: trigonometry, education, alternative-proof

I have a right triangle, $AH\perp BC$, where $\cos \beta=\sqrt 5/5$ and $\overline{AH}+\overline{CH}+\overline{HB}=7$.

[image]

I have to found the area.

**My steps (or solution)**:

$$\mathcal A(\triangle ABC)=\frac 12\overline{AB}\cdot \overline{BC} \sin \beta$$
with $0<\beta<\pi$. Hence $\sin \beta=\sqrt{1-5/25}=2\sqrt5/5$. But $\overline{AB}=\overline{BC}\cos \beta$ and the area

$$\mathcal A(\triangle ABC)=\frac12(\overline{BC}\cos \beta)\cdot (\overline{BC}\sin \beta)=\frac12\overline{BC}^2 \tag 1$$

We know that:

$$\overline{AH}+\overline{CH}+\overline{HB}=7, \quad \text{with}\quad  \overline{CH}+\overline{HB}=\overline{BC}$$
Hence
$$\overline{AH}+\overline{BC}=7 \iff \overline{BC}=7-\overline{AH}$$
and $\overline{AH}=\overline{AB}\cos\gamma=\overline{BC}\cos\gamma\cos\beta$.

Putting this last identity to the condition $\overline{BC}=7-\overline{AH}$ I will have:
$$\overline{BC}=7-\overline{BC}\cos\gamma\cos\beta \iff \overline{BC}(1+\cos\gamma\cos\beta)=7$$
After,
$$\overline{BC}=\frac{7}{1+\cos\gamma\cos\beta}$$
with $\cos \gamma=\cos(\pi/2-\cos\beta)=\sin\beta=2\sqrt5/5$.
Definitively
$$\overline{BC}^2=\frac{49}{\left(1+\frac 25\right)^2}=\frac{49}{\frac{49}{25}}$$
and
$$\mathcal{A}(\triangle ABC)=\frac15\overline{BC}^2=5 \tag 2$$

I'm very tired and often don't find immediate solutions to problems. I had thought of using Euclid's second theorem by placing
$\overline{AH}=x$ and $\overline{BC}=y$, and $x+y=7$. After I will have $x^2=\overline{BH}\cdot \overline{CH}$. But I have left this path.

> Can this possible alternative be used or is there another more immediate way?

Comment: Is $\angle AHB$ right? (Diagram seems to imply this, but it's inaccurate and the problem cannot be solved without it.)

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Hi, yes it is the height relating to the hypotenuse.

Comment: "Congrats", your question is now [used](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1604039) for review audits :) best wishes

Comment: @CalvinKhor Hi . Thank you very much for your comment and for your wishes. I will give the same wishes and best regards to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\cos \beta = \frac{|AB|}{|BC|} = \frac{\sqrt 5}{5},\quad  \sin \beta = \frac{|AH|}{|AB|} = \frac{2\sqrt 5}{5}$$

Given $|AB|: |BC| = \sqrt5:5$, we assume $$|AB| = \sqrt5k, |BC| = 5k $$ where $k$ is a constant. Now using $$\frac{|AH|}{|AB|} = \frac{2\sqrt 5}{5}, \quad |AH| = 2k$$

$$|AH| + |BH| + |HC| = |AH| + |BC| = 7k = 7\implies k = 1.$$

So, $$|AH| = 2, |BC| = 5 \implies \mathcal{A}(\triangle ABC) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot |AH| \cdot |BC| = 5.$$

Comment: Hi,  why do you have used $k$? What is $k$? Can you explain me....I am very tired...excuse me.

Comment: :) no problem. $k$ is any constant. I am writing $BC = 5k$ for ease of working, as $AB$ and $BC$ are in the ratio $\sqrt5:5$.

Comment: I'm very tired. Can you edit your answer (I not see often the comments) to know the reason: $|BC| = 5k,\quad  |AB| = \sqrt5 k, \quad |AH| = 2k$, please? What is the generic value of $k$?

Comment: ok, will do in sometime

Comment: Thank you very much...and you not forgot it :-)

Comment: I like your solution, congratulations.

Comment: @Sebastiano I edited. I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes I have seen ....immediately. Thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu.

Answer (score 3):

The picture should really look like this:

[image]

We have $\sin\beta=2/\sqrt5$ and $\tan\beta=CA/AB=2$. Then $HB,HA,HC$ are in geometric progression with ratio $2$; since their sum is $7$ it can easily be worked out that the hypotenuse $BC$ is $5$. Then $AB/BC=\cos\beta$ gives $AB=\sqrt5$, $CA=2\sqrt5$ and $A(\triangle ABC)=5$.

Comment: Thank you very much....I have not understood the assert: Then HB,HA,HC are in geometric progression with ratio 2. Please, can you explain better this concept that I now, playing the guitar, I not remember.

Comment: @Sebastiano $\triangle AHB,CHA,CAB$ are all similar.

Comment: Yes of course (they are all right triangles) but do write you as a geometric progression? You can, please, write all the steps? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Angelo It is done with the hand :-(, "no dai" :-(

Comment: My $3$-year-old niece can draw better than @ParclyTaxel.

Comment: @Angelo Can you please delete your last comment? I'm asking you please.

Comment: Why have I to delete it? My niece is good at drawing and without a doubt she is better than @ParclyTaxel.

Comment: Truly @Parcly Taxel seems to draw as Mr Bean does.

Comment: @Angelo No disdain and I don't like disputes. I'm sick of the quarrels :-(

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Let $a = \overline{AH}$, $b = \overline{CH}$ and $c = \overline{HB}$. Then we have that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
a = \tan(\beta)c\\\\
a = \tan(\pi/2 - \beta)b
\end{cases} \Rightarrow a(1 + \tan(\beta) + \cot(\beta)) = 7
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2):

$\cos\beta=\dfrac{\sqrt5}{5}$ and $\sin\beta=\dfrac{2\sqrt5}{5}.$ Let $\overline{AH}=x,$ then you can obtain values $$\overline{AB}= \dfrac{\sqrt{5}x}{2},\qquad \overline{BC}= \dfrac{5x}{2},\qquad \overline{AC}=\sqrt{5}x$$ and $$\overline{AH}=x,\qquad \overline{BH}=\dfrac{x}{2},\qquad \overline{CH}=2x$$ using simple trigonometry. Now, compute the value of $x$ via $\overline{AH}+\overline{BH}+\overline{CH}=7$ and use it to compute the area.

Comment: Thank you very much also to you. There is a missing \ for the `cos \beta` in meantime :-). Certainly now I have not understood the $\overline{AB}= \dfrac{\sqrt{5}x}{2},\qquad \overline{BC}= \dfrac{5x}{2},\qquad \overline{AC}=\sqrt{5}x$ and $\overline{AH}=x,\qquad \overline{BH}=\dfrac{x}{2},\qquad \overline{CH}=2x$. For all the users +1.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. Note that $\hat{CAH}=\beta$ and just use definitions of sine and cosine ratios to find lengths of unknown sides using the only known length $\overline{AH}=x.$

Comment: Ahahah don't worry...I use often $\LaTeX$ and mathjax :-)

Answer (score 1):

HINT

[image]

Start with length of $ HB =1$.

Chase the sides using Pythagoras thm. A property of right triangles can be used ( square of altitude equals product of base segments ; $HC=HA^2/HB$).

$$\text{ScaleFactor=}\frac{7}{4+2+1}=1$$

$$\text{Area = ScaleFactor}^2 \cdot \frac12 \cdot (4+1) \cdot 2 =5. $$

Comment: Hi and thank you very very much. I have not understood your assert "*A property of right triangles can be used (square of altitude equals product of base segments)*". Is it $HB:AH=AH=HC$? Where have you taken the last two proprieties (can you explain, better - I not remember this? I am very tired and do now at the end of the school year to be lucid) ...+1 for the answer?

Comment: Yes,  ok; your typo. $ = AH:HC$

Comment: Thank you very much. What is the scalefactor? How I obtain the last two formulas, please?

Comment: Suppose if the sum of the three sides is given as 350. Then you need to scale up all the side 50 times.. and area 2500 times. ok?

Comment: Ok. :-) perfect!